# Adding \part to TOC, format mismatch

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

In the following MWE I've defined the format of `\part` in the toc and in the text to be centered and in uppercase. In case I just have one `\part` heading in the document I need this heading without number so I went for `\part*` but I need it nevertheless in the toc so I went for `\addcontentsline` which results in left aligned toc entry... How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pagsize]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}

\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{}{\protect\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect \centering\MakeUppercase{#1. #2}}}
}

\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\Large
\begin{center}
\thepart\autodot 
\end{center}}
\addtokomafont{part}{\centering\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\hrule
\part*{Memo}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Memo}

\section{}
text text
\part{Outlook}
\label{sec:Outlook}
text text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried `\addpart` instead of `\part*`?

Comment: `\centering` and `\MakeUppercase` are not font commands and should not be used at `\addtokomafont`. `center` environment adds extra vertical space. There is a command `\raggedpart` to change the alignment of the part heading. And you could redefine `\partlinesformat`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Do you mean`\partlineswithprefixformat`? This command will be available in the next KOMA-Script version (3.25).

Comment: @esdd §€@&¬! long macro names … ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `\addpart` instead of `\part*`, which automatically creates the TOC entry. Please note that I've added a test, if there's a number, because you would have got a dot otherwise.

[image: addpart]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pagsize]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\cftpagenumbersoff{part}

\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{part}{}{\protect\parbox{\textwidth}{\protect\centering\MakeUppercase{\ifstrempty{#1}{}{#1. }#2}}}
}

\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\Large
\begin{center}
\thepart\autodot 
\end{center}}
\addtokomafont{part}{\centering\large\bfseries\MakeUppercase}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\hrule
\addpart{Memo}

\section{}
text text
\part{Outlook}
\label{sec:Outlook}
text text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm...  Thank you. I still am wondering how you all got your knowledge from. I've got 4 Latex books at home, non of it delivers this ;)

Comment: @Jerry-Jee: Apparently none of those books treat with KOMA? ;-) And `tocloft` in conjunction with `KOMA` is weird

Comment: I read the KOMA Documentation, but was more successfull with tocloft.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use package `tocloft` together with a KOMA-Script class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pagesize]{scrartcl}[2016/05/10]% needs version 3.20 or newer
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{}
    {\addtocentrydefault{part}{}{\MakeUppercase{#2}}}
    {\addtocentrydefault{part}{}{#1\autodot\enskip\MakeUppercase{#2}}}%
}

\renewcommand*\raggedpart{\centering}
\renewcommand*\partformat{\thepart\autodot\par\bigskip}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\large\MakeUppercase,
  prefixfont=\Large,
  tocnumwidth=0pt,
  toclinefill={},
  tocpagenumberformat=\nopagenumber,
  tocentryformat=\parttocentryformat,
]{part}
\newcommand\nopagenumber[1]{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\parttocentryformat[1]{%
  \renewcommand\@pnumwidth{0pt}
  \usekomafont{partentry}\centering{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\hrule
\addpart{Memo}

\section{A section}
text text
\part{Outlook}
\label{sec:Outlook}
\KOMAScriptVersion
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

The next (not yet on CTAN) **KOMA-Script version 3.25** will define und use command `\partlineswithprefixcommand` to format the layout of part headings. Then `\MakeUppercase` should be removed from the font settings because it is not a font command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,pagesize]{scrartcl}[2017/09/07]% needs KOMA-Script version prerelease 3.25 or newer 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\renewcommand*{\addparttocentry}[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{}
    {\addtocentrydefault{part}{}{\MakeUppercase{#2}}}
    {\addtocentrydefault{part}{}{#1\autodot\enskip\MakeUppercase{#2}}}%
}

\renewcommand*\raggedpart{\centering}
\renewcommand*\partformat{\thepart\autodot}
\renewcommand*\partlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
  #2\par\bigskip\MakeUppercase{#3}%
}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  font=\large,
  prefixfont=\Large,
  tocnumwidth=0pt,
  toclinefill={},
  tocpagenumberformat=\nopagenumber,
  tocentryformat=\parttocentry,
]{part}
\newcommand\nopagenumber[1]{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\parttocentry[1]{%
  \renewcommand\@pnumwidth{0pt}
  \usekomafont{partentry}\centering{#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\hrule
\addpart{Memo}

\section{A section}
text text
\part{Outlook}
\label{sec:Outlook}
\KOMAScriptVersion{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response as well, I have the komabook but now and have just recognized that the most current scrguide deviates from it and delivers your solution. without this new long command of course.